# Mongoose JobSchema.pre('update', function(n){n()}) throws: TypeError: Cannot read property 'numAsyncPres' of undefined

Tags: mongoose, pre

I have this Schema in mongoose and when I use the pre with update, I get this error.

```
JobSchema.pre('update', function(n){n()})
```

Full error

```
C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:413
        throw err;
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'numAsyncPres' of undefined
    at Model._lazySetupHooks (C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\hooks\hooks.js:149:49)
    at Model.pre (C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\hooks\hooks.js:113:10)
    at Model.doQueue (C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1116:41)
    at Model.Document (C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:55:8)
    at Model.Model (C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:26:12)
    at Model.model (C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:910:11)
    at new Model (C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:418:15)
    at cb (C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:804:16)
    at C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\lib\utils.js:408:16
    at C:\web\production01_server\node_modules\production\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\cursor.js:133:9
```

Notes:

- pre('save' WORKS
- post('update' Doesn't throw error and doesn't works

Answer (score 10):

Mongoose 4.0 supports pre update hooks via Query middleware.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

```
schema.pre('update', function() {
  console.log(this instanceof mongoose.Query); // true
  this.start = Date.now();
});

schema.post('update', function() {
  console.log(this instanceof mongoose.Query); // true
  console.log('update() took ' + (Date.now() - this.start) + ' millis');
});
```

A note of caution:

> "**Query** middleware differs from **document** middleware in a subtle but
>   important way: in document middleware, this refers to the document
>   being updated. In query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have
>   a reference to the document being updated, so **this** refers to the **query
>   object** rather than the **document** being updated."

Comment: +1 for actually looking into the documentation. Also people please read: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/wiki/4.0-Release-Notes, there are lots of breaking changes in 4.x.x

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html), the pre and post middleware functions support:

- init
- validate
- save
- remove

No support for update.

Comment: Greg, suppose i have a update user function, can you guide me how can i hash the **user's password** again whle **updating the user's pasword**, i used to do that while creating the user, in **pre save hook**

Answer (score 3):

It's true that Mongoose doesn't support hooks on Model APIs other than those Greg listed above. However, an update hook can be done via Monkey-patch. The [Hooker NPM](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hooker) package is a good way of doing this cleanly.

The [RESTeasy](https://www.npmjs.org/package/hooker) project which is a Boilerplate for Node REST APIs has code that demonstrates how to do it:

```
var hooker = require('hooker');

var BaseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sampleString: {
    type: String
  }
});

var BaseModel = mongoose.model('Base', BaseSchema);

// Utilize hooks for update operations. We do it in this way because MongooseJS
// does not natively support update hooks at the Schema level. This is a way
// to support it.
hooker.hook (BaseModel, 'update', {
  pre: function () {
    // Insert any logic you want before updating to occur here
    console.log('BaseModel pre update');
  },
  post: function () {
    // Insert any logic you want after updating to occur here
    console.log('BaseModel post update');
  }
});

// Export the Mongoose model
module.exports = BaseModel;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/538
So no pre for update...