# Mongoose.js update doc and use middleware

Tags: mongoose

What is the best way to update document and use post update middleware (code that will be called automatically after update).

To update document with data object I do the following:

```
DocModel.findByIdAndUpdate(id, data, function(err, doc){    
    // But after update is completed I would like 
    // some model's middleware function to be called, 
    // but there is only: init, save, remove, validate, 
    // and no update type of middleware
    //save middleware is not called in this scenario 
    //so I can call save for example
   doc.save(function(err, doc){
       ....
       // after save is completed middleware will be called
   })   
})
```

I wonder If this could be simplified.

Comment: see [pre('update') throws error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761819/mongoose-jobschema-preupdate-functionnn-throws-typeerror-cannot-rea) related question

Comment: I know that there is no pre('update')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this. Notice that the middleware is only called when using `save()` method.

```
schema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this._wasNew = this.isNew;
  return next();
});

schema.post('save', function() {
    if (this._wasNew) {
      console.log('created')
    } else {
      console.log('updated')
    }
});
```

Comment: Well I wanted middleware for update method, but it is impossible as mongoose's update is raw method that just maps to mongodb driver's update.

Comment: with the code above you can simulate a post('update'), but yes, if you have to use `update` method instead of `save` you can't use middleware